# How do I ensure that copyright notices accompany all of my source files for a java-maven build?

Tags: java, maven-2, checkstyle, copyright-display

Is there a standard way people enforce the inclusion of copyright notices in their java/maven builds?  I realize that it shouldn't be necessary since the product itself is copy-written and if someone has my source I have much bigger problems, but I'm being asked to check and was wondering if checkstyle, PMD or something else handled this automatically.

Is there a tool which handles checking for copyright?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, Checkstyle (and the [maven-checkstyle-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/)) can do that, it can check that every source files do contain a license header. Put that header in a text file and use the [`headerLocation`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/checkstyle-mojo.html#headerLocation) to point on it (it uses by default `LICENSE.txt`).

Let's say you want to use `checkstyle.license` for your copyright notices. For a multi-modules build, the standard approach is to create a dedicated module to host Checkstyle resources (see [Multimodule configuration](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html)):

```
whizbang
|-- pom.xml
|-- build-tools
|   |-- src
|   |   `-- main
|   |       `-- resources
|   |           `-- whizbang
|   |               |-- checkstyle.xml
|   |               `-- checkstyle.license
|   `-- pom.xml
|-- core
|-- gui
|-- jmx
`-- src
```

Then, include the Checkstyle [configuration](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/plugin-info.html) in the top level `pom.xml`.

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <!-- Apply checkstyle rules and fail the build in case of errors. The
         checkstyle config files are taken from the build-tools JAR module.-->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <!-- Lock down plugin version for build reproducibility -->
      <version>2.4</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.example.whizbang</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <configuration>
        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
        <configLocation>whizbang/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
        <headerLocation>whizbang/checkstyle.license</headerLocation>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

This setup will ensure that a copyright header is present in source files (and apply other Checkstyle rules but this is another story). Adapt it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I just found 
http://code.google.com/p/maven-license-plugin/
seems reasonable too

Answer (score 0):

If your project is in a Git repository, you can follow the [REUSE standard](https://reuse.software) from the Free Software Foundation Europe. With the [reuse-tool](https://github.com/fsfe/reuse-tool) you can check REUSE compliance by executing `reuse lint`. For continuous integration (CI) you can use the [fsfe/reuse](https://hub.docker.com/r/fsfe/reuse) Docker image.